# DVWA Installation issue

Tags: php, mysql

After 72 hours trying to install this I come here. I need help with the following error:

### Database Setup

Click on the 'Create / Reset Database' button below to create or reset your database.
If you get an error make sure you have the correct user credentials in: `/var/www/html/dvwa/config/config.inc.php`

If the database already exists, it will be cleared and the data will be reset.
You can also use this to reset the administrator credentials ("admin // password") at any stage.

### Setup Check

```
Operating system: *nix
Backend database: MySQL
PHP version: 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

Web Server SERVER_NAME: 127.0.0.1

PHP function display_errors: Disabled
PHP function safe_mode: Disabled
PHP function allow_url_include: Disabled
PHP function allow_url_fopen: Enabled
PHP function magic_quotes_gpc: Disabled
PHP module php-gd: Missing
```

Comment: You have missing `php-gd` library, install it using `sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd` assuming you are using Ubuntu. If your distribution is different follow its specific installation instruction. Once `php-gd` is installed retry your installation.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint. I did what you mentioned and it installed but I still get the same error.

Comment: This time you must be getting error on something else missing. Could you post your error message as well?